# How do I remove contextmenu items based on pivotitem in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

This is for Windows Phone 7.5

I am not able to remove menuitems from my contextmenu based on the pivotitem. I have three pivotitems and I need to show the custom items in the context menu.

I am trying to find the right event that can help me capture the current pivot item and based on that I would like to present context menu options.

Update #1:

Xaml Markup:

```
 <controls:PivotItem x:Name="HighPivotItem" Header="high">
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened" 
                           Closed="ContextMenu_Closed">
                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="mark as done" Click="MarkMenuItem_Click"/>
                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="edit" Click="EditMenuItem_Click"/>
                <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete" Click="DeleteMenuItem_Click"/>
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="HighTextBlock" Text=""
      Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="22,17,0,0"
 Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}" />

            <ListBox x:Name="HighListBox" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"
             SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" />
        </Grid>
    </controls:PivotItem>
```

Here is the code in my event:

```
void MarkMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Task task = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as Task;

  // Move from the task list to the done list
  Settings.TaskList.Value.Remove(task);
  Settings.DoneList.Value.Add(task);

  RefreshLists();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be designing your context menus per pivot item

```
        <controls:Pivot Title="Pivot">
            <controls:PivotItem Header="one" DataContext="{Binding Task}">
                <!-- Stuff for pivot ONE -->
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu >
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Menu for both"/>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Menu for item ONE"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </controls:PivotItem>
            <controls:PivotItem Header="two">
                <!-- Stuff for pivot TWO -->
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu >
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Menu for both"/>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Menu for item TWO"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </controls:PivotItem>
        </controls:Pivot>
```

The menus can be placed into a datatemplate for a listbox, or onto individual items.

The example above assumes that the page has a DataContext that has a property "Task"

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel { Task = new Task() };
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: This works and I can see context menu but now the events are not getting the menu items. They are coming out as null so the actions are not working. I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: added code snippets..it is the task that is coming back as null.

Comment: In your sample code I do not see the datacontext being set to anything for the PivotItem. Make sure that the DataContext of your PivotItem is binding properly to a property of the DataContext of the overall page

Comment: Hmmm. I have the databinding inside a grid. All I did was moved by contextmenu from a data template to individual pivot items. Nothing should have broken.

Comment: Can you update your xaml/code to more reflect what you are doing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11436/discussion-between-codetoglory-and-shawn-kendrot)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This fixed my issue and also great way to refactor into a user control.